# Why is the return value always 0 from getSelectedIndex from a DefaultListModel?

Tags: codenameone

I have an AutoCompleteTextField working with a DefaultListModel.

```
        options = new DefaultListModel<>();
    labelACField = new AutoCompleteTextField(options){
        @Override
        protected boolean filter(String text) {

        }
    };
```

The return value from options.getSelectedIndex() always returns 0 from actionPerformed, even users choose other items in the AutoCompleteTextField.

```
labelACField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            if (filteredIdObjs!=null){
                selectedIdx = options.getSelectedIndex();
```

For example, a user clicks "VV Vanguard Large-Cap ETF" or IVOV....or IVVD, or CVV.. the return value from options.getSelectedIndex() always returns 0.
How do I get the item index that the user clicks?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an interface designed for a List. `AutoCompleteTextField` uses the `ListModel` interface for ease of use. But it doesn't use selection since it's inherently a text field.

The output is the text within the text field. Not list selection since a user can type in any arbitrary value without selecting a value from the list.

Comment: Could I combine ListModel with the List component for the selection of items in ListModel? Would you provide examples?
Thank you.

Comment: See the search toolbar sample [here](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Toolbar.html). There's also the [FilterProxyListModel](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/list/FilterProxyListModel.html).